# Stainless steel

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I've some doubts about [stainless steel](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Stainless_Steel_Blocks), hope someone can clarify:

1. It's only 2000 more durability compared to [steel block](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Steel_Blocks), what is the point? Steel already offer whopping 19000 cumulative durability, why would I want to upgrade it more with the [rare resource](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Reinforced_steel_upgrade)?
2. How do I repair stainless steel? The wiki seems silent about what materials are used to repair blocks (or I am blind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that it's just one more layer of protection. When you upgrade a steel block to stainless steel, it adds that 2000 durability. Whether or not it's worth it is entirely up to you.

In order to repair it, you need the same trader-sold materials, just as you need steel bars to repair a steel block. Personally I find stainless steel to be a money sink if you have way too much money and nothing to spend it on, which I would think is common in many end-game (300+ day) scenarios.

Comment: In addition, while Stainless steel only adds an additional 2000 HP it's main purpose is that it severely increases the Blocks explosion resistance, TNT, Exploding Cops, etc.. Not sure about Vomit.

Comment: @Fran, any proofs for damage resistance from game configs?

Comment: Worth mention that even though it is not cost-effective, it is still the only way to get maximum durability. There is no choice Steel or Stainless Steel, there is only amount of money(time) you want to invest in base.

Comment: @Sanctus Make a Creative Game make a cage out of of stainless steal. Spawn a cop in each and shoot it till it blows up. Then you can see with a repair tool in your hand the damage done. I don't know if it also helps against barrel explosions, but worth a test to see if there is a difference in damage points.